# Error when trying to create a Hive table using a custom SerDe

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have a file containing data that needs to be uploaded to a Hive table. I wrote a custom SerDe (which is basically a modification of the Regex Serde already available with Hive) to help me upload the data.

This is the SerDe that I wrote

```
package my.hive.customserde;

public class FIASC2 extends AbstractSerDe {

    public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(FIASC2.class.getName());

    int colwidths[] = {1, 10, 6, 12, 8, 14, 16, 6, 6, 2, 10, 10, 19, 2, 2, 6, 8, 1};
    String outputformat = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s "
        + "%16$s %17$s %18$s";


    int datetimecols[] = {5};
    int datecols[] = {17};
    String cols;
    int numColumns;
    int totalcolwidth = 0;

    List<String> columnNames;
    List<TypeInfo> columnTypes;

    ArrayList<String> row;
    StructObjectInspector rowOI;

    Object[] outputFields;
    Text outputRowText;


@Override
    public void initialize(Configuration conf, Properties tbl) throws SerDeException {
        LOG.debug("Initializing SerDe");
        // Get column names
        String columnNameProperty = tbl.getProperty(serdeConstants.LIST_COLUMNS);
        String columnTypeProperty = tbl.getProperty(serdeConstants.LIST_COLUMN_TYPES);
        LOG.debug("Columns : " + columnNameProperty + "Types : " + columnTypeProperty);

        if(columnNameProperty.length() == 0) {
             columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        else {
             columnNames = Arrays.asList(columnNameProperty.split(","));
        }

        columnTypes = TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(columnTypeProperty);

        assert columnNames.size() == columnTypes.size();
        assert colwidths.length == columnNames.size();

        numColumns = columnNames.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
             totalcolwidth += i;
        }

        List<ObjectInspector> columnOIs = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>(columnNames.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
             columnOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
        }

        rowOI = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(columnNames, columnOIs);

        row = new ArrayList<String>(numColumns);

        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            row.add(null);
        }

        outputFields = new Object[numColumns];
        outputRowText = new Text();
}


@Override
    public Object deserialize(Writable blob) throws SerDeException {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Text rowText = (Text) blob;
        int index = 0;

        if(rowText.toString().length() < totalcolwidth) {
             return null;
        }

        if((rowText.toString().substring(0, 1) == "H") || (rowText.toString().substring(0, 1) == "T")) {
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            int len = colwidths[i];
            String col = rowText.toString().substring(index, index + len);
        // Convert the datetime string into the correct format so that it can be uploaded to the hive table
            if(Arrays.asList(datetimecols).contains(i)) {
                 DateTimeFormatConverter dtc = new DateTimeFormatConverter();
                try {
                    col = dtc.convertCurrToNew(col);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    LOG.error("Unable to parse Date Time string : " + col);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(datecols).contains(i)) {
                 DateFormatConverter dtc = new DateFormatConverter();
                try {
                    col = dtc.convertCurrToNew(col);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    LOG.error("Unable to parse Date String : " + col);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            row.set(i, col);
            index += len;
        }

        return row;
    }


@Override
    public ObjectInspector getObjectInspector() throws SerDeException {
        return rowOI;
    }


    @Override
    public SerDeStats getSerDeStats() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

@Override
    public Class<? extends Writable> getSerializedClass() {
        return Text.class;
    }


    @Override
    public Writable serialize(Object obj, ObjectInspector objInspector) throws SerDeException {
        if(outputformat == null) {
            throw new SerDeException("Cannot write into table because no output format was specified");
        }

        StructObjectInspector outputRowOI = (StructObjectInspector) objInspector;
        List<? extends StructField> outputFieldRefs = outputRowOI.getAllStructFieldRefs();

        if(outputFieldRefs.size() != numColumns) {
            throw new SerDeException("Output format does not have the same number fields as the number of columns");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            Object field = outputRowOI.getStructFieldData(obj, outputFieldRefs.get(i));
            ObjectInspector fieldOI = outputFieldRefs.get(i).getFieldObjectInspector();

            StringObjectInspector fieldStringOI = (StringObjectInspector) fieldOI;


            outputFields[i] = fieldStringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(field);
        }

        String outputRowString = null;

        try {
             outputRowString = String.format(outputformat, outputFields);
        } catch (MissingFormatArgumentException e) {
             throw new SerDeException("The table contains " + numColumns + "columns but the output format requires more", e);
        }

        outputRowText.set(outputRowString);

        return outputRowText;
     }
```

}

You can be rest assured that I have imported every class that needs to be imported.

When I try to create the table, I get an error saying "Unable to get field from serde : my.hive.customserde.FIASC2"

Here is the stacktrace

```
2015-08-25 15:57:51,995 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-57]: metadata.Table (Table.java:getCols(608)) - Unable to get field from serde: my.hive.customserde.FIASC2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getFieldsFromDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:1257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1054)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:154)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-25 15:57:51,996 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-57]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:failed(520)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1054)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:154)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getFieldsFromDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:1257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:695)
    ... 21 more
```

I understand that the table creation failed. But does anyone know why am I getting this error? I tried googling, but didn't get a lot of help.

If it is of any help, here is the create table script that I am using.

```
create table if not exists fiasc2(
record_type varchar(1),
fin_id varchar(16),
corp_id varchar(8),
merc_id varchar(16),
term_id varchar(8),
tran_time timestamp,
cashcard_number varchar(16),
ttc varchar(8),
tcc varchar(8),
tran_type varchar(2),
tran_amount varchar(16),
deposit_amount varchar(16),
pan varchar(32),
account_type varchar(2),
response_code varchar(2),
card_balance varchar(8),
settlement_date date,
tran_mode varchar(1))
row format serde 'my.hive.customserde.FIASC2'
location '/user/hive/fiasc2_test';
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds familiar.
You are returning `null` SerDeStats and that is the only thing I've seen that may be null and it rings a bell, I think I had the same issue with my JSON SerDe when they introduced SerdeStats a few versions of hive ago.
Try:

```
// add this to the members
private SerDeStats stats;
// ...
public void initialize(Configuration conf, Properties tbl) throws SerDeException {
..
 // add this in initialize()
 stats = new SerDeStats();

// and of course here
@Override
public SerDeStats getSerDeStats() {
    return stats;
}
```